# What causes intoxication for Dark Eldar?

Tags: rogue-trader, warhammer-40k

Ok so in our adventures, I found a Flask of unknown contents. Long story short: wanted to know what was in it, so I put a bit in the Dark Eldar's food, next thing we know, he's passed out cold from intoxication (so says the GM).

Going off the fact that basic stim and detox don't work on Dark Eldar, is it possible that Dark Eldar may get incredibly drunk from something standard to humans? (When they consume potatoes and it turns into vodka perhaps?)

Comment: It's possible, even likely, that your GM just made something up.

Comment: Probably. Just thought that being a Xeno they'd be more succeptible to some things rather than others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely.  The Dark Eldar seek out ever more extreme stimuli to subject themselves and others to.  Any substance that can knock a Dark Eldar unconcious is either incredibly rare, impossible to develop a tolerance against (presumable even with biological augmentation, which the Dark Eldar seem to be into), or so potent a single drop would kill ten sturdy men.  Certainly things common in human society, a race against which they make frequent raiding excursions, should not have much effect on them at all, even though, as you hint at, the biological ramifications of certain substances might be different.

If the being in question were a non-dark Eldar my answer would be yes.

I think it more likely that the contents of the flask in question are a MacGuffin or that your GM made a mistake.

Comment: I'm really just starting to think it's a bit of fluff. The GM has hinted that this flask belonged to a member of his old troupe. But was hush-hush on the specifics of what is is/does/how it works.